# MongoDB: How to remove an index on a replicaset?

Tags: mongodb

I see that the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-indexes/) says that removing index is by calling `db.accounts.dropIndex( { "tax-id": 1 } )`. But it does not say whether the node needs to be removed from the replicaset or not.

I tried to take a secondary node in a replicaset offline and restart as a standalone node (in a different port) and tried to drop the index.

But after bringing back the node in the replica set with regular process `sudo service mongod start`, the mongod process is dying saying the index got corrupted.

```
 Thu Oct 31 19:52:38.098 [repl writer worker 1] Assertion: 15898:error in index possibly corruption consider repairing 382
0xdddd81 0xd9f55b 0xd9fa9c 0x7edb83 0x7fb332 0x7fdc08 0x9d3b50 0x9c796e 0x9deb64 0xac45dd 0xac58df 0xa903fa 0xa924c7 0xa71f6c 0xc273d3 0xc26b18 0xdab721 0xe26609 0x7ff4d05f0c6b 0x7ff4cf9965ed
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdddd81]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x9b) [0xd9f55b]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xd9fa9c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11checkFailedEj+0x143) [0x7edb83]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo12BucketBasicsINS_12BtreeData_V1EE11basicInsertENS_7DiskLocERiS3_RKNS_5KeyV1ERKNS_8OrderingE+0x222) [0x7fb332]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo11BtreeBucketINS_12BtreeData_V1EE10insertHereENS_7DiskLocEiS3_RKNS_5KeyV1ERKNS_8OrderingES3_S3_RNS_12IndexDetailsE+0x68) [0x7fdc08]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZNK5mongo30IndexInsertionContinuationImplINS_12BtreeData_V1EE22doIndexInsertionWritesEv+0xa0) [0x9d3b50]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14IndexInterface13IndexInserter19finishAllInsertionsEv+0x1e) [0x9c796e]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo24indexRecordUsingTwoStepsEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsENS_7BSONObjENS_7DiskLocEb+0x754) [0x9deb64]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibbbPb+0x123d) [0xac45dd]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr16insertWithObjModEPKcRNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x4f) [0xac58df]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo14_updateObjectsEbPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEPNS_11RemoveSaverEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyEb+0x2eda) [0xa903fa]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo27updateObjectsForReplicationEPKcRKNS_7BSONObjES4_bbbRNS_7OpDebugEbRKNS_24QueryPlanSelectionPolicyE+0xb7) [0xa924c7]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo21applyOperation_inlockERKNS_7BSONObjEbb+0x65c) [0xa71f6c]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset8SyncTail9syncApplyERKNS_7BSONObjEb+0x713) [0xc273d3]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x48) [0xc26b18]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xdab721]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe26609]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7c6b) [0x7ff4d05f0c6b]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7ff4cf9965ed]
Thu Oct 31 19:52:38.106 [repl writer worker 1] ERROR: writer worker caught exception: error in index possibly corruption consider repairing 382 on:
```

xxxxxxxx--deleted content related to the data...xxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
Thu Oct 31 19:52:38.106 [repl writer worker 1]   Fatal Assertion 16360
0xdddd81 0xd9dc13 0xc26bfc 0xdab721 0xe26609 0x7ff4d05f0c6b 0x7ff4cf9965ed
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0xdddd81]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo13fassertFailedEi+0xa3) [0xd9dc13]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo7replset14multiSyncApplyERKSt6vectorINS_7BSONObjESaIS2_EEPNS0_8SyncTailE+0x12c) [0xc26bfc]
 /usr/bin/mongod(_ZN5mongo10threadpool6Worker4loopEv+0x281) [0xdab721]
 /usr/bin/mongod() [0xe26609]
 /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7c6b) [0x7ff4d05f0c6b]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7ff4cf9965ed]
Thu Oct 31 19:52:38.108 [repl writer worker 1]

***aborting after fassert() failure


Thu Oct 31 19:52:38.108 Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

Is this due to dropping the index in the offline mode on the secondary? Any suggestions on the proper way to drop the index is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to remove index from replica set is to drop it on primary. The idea of replica is having the same copy of data (with small time lags). So whenever you do something on primary is copied to the secondaries. So if you start doing anything on the primary, right after it finishes this process, the process propagates to secondaries.

If you are removing index from primary - the index will be removed on the secondary as well.

Comment: and yet that is *not* the recommended method of adding indexes to a replica set at all. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/

Comment: @SalvadorDali Thanks for your suggestion. Will try that as a last option, as there is a lot of data involved and am afraid the write lock on the replicaset during that time would make the entire replicaset blocked, till the drop index is complete.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The way it worked for us to drop the indexes in replicaset (apart from issuing drop index from the primary, as mentioned above) is to stop the write traffic, stop the primary and do the drop indexes on all the nodes and bring every node back into the replica set. This involved disruption to our write traffic though.

Comment: @oliTwist that was unneccessary though - dropIndex() is not an intensive command like ensureIndex, but even if it was, you could do it on each member of the replica set using this method docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets so downtime is *not* required.